# Oracle SQL comparing values

Tags: sql, oracle

In a relational database with a users and a friends table, I am trying to determine pairs of users of the opposite sex who are friends. 
So, user a can potentially be friends with user b, but not the other way around. I want to find all instances where a is friends with b and b is also friends with a. I have a query that returns all the one way friendships to the opposite sex but am not sure how to further reduce the answer to take out non matched pairs.

This is the structure of the tables:

```
Table: users
Attributes: id, name, gender
Table: friends
Attributes: id1, id2, startdate
```

Comment: Second query is redundant. First found all friends

Comment: There is probably another way to write it, but it's not redundant as the id1 and id2 are swapped from male to female, therefore completing the query with all friendships initiated from either person. The results are not duplicated.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand question - what do you need as result - matched pairs or list of users who have no pairs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all mutual M-F friendships, assuming gender is always M or F:

```
select distinct a.name, a.id, b.name, b.id
from users a, users b, friends f1, friends f2
where f1.id1 = a.id
and f1.id2 = b.id
and a.gender != b.gender
and f2.id1 = b.id
and f2.id2 = a.id;
```

Or, use ANSI join syntax:

```
select distinct a.name, a.id, b.name, b.id
from   friends f1
join   friends f2 on f1.id1 = f2.id2 and f1.id2 = f2.id1
join   users a    on a.id = f1.id1
join   users b    on b.id = f1.id2
where  a.gender != b.gender;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INTERSECT` instead of `UNION`. You want the records that are present in both sub-queries. (You probably don't need the `DISTINCT`s either.)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, INTERSECT is completely different to MINUS, and both are supported by Oracle...

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: ah, you are right....